# Load active properties file spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I want to read values from an active profile or can say active properties file.
I have three properties files

- application-dev.properties
- application-stage.properties
- application-prod.properties

I have set an active profile to `dev` as follows

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

My `application-dev.properties` file has one entry that i want to read in my class.

**application-dev.properties** file

```
fix.connection.type=initiator
```

I tried reading this entry

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
@Component
public class AdaptorDestination {
    @Value("${fix.connection.type}")
    private String connectionType;
}
```

**Exception**

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.profiles.active' in value "classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"
```

Please help me out

Comment: Just remove `@PropertySource("classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")`. Spring-boot will load the correct property-file for you.

Comment: still facing the same issue...@DirkDeyne

Comment: `Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'fix.connection.type' in value "${fix.connection.type}"`

Comment: and do not use  `@Component` and `@Configuration` on same class

Comment: it still gives the same exeption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `@PropertySource` annotation in order to load a property using `@Value` annotation.
Spring will load `@Value` property automatically from the current active profile.

Also, you don't need to specify `${spring.profiles.active}` in the `@PropertySource` annotation as Spring always loads properties from the currently active profile by default.
Spring automatically resolves file name based on the profile suffix.

So you need only specify the base filename, e.g.:
`@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")`
If the currently active profile is "dev" Spring will load properties at first from `application.properties` file and then override them with properties from `application-dev.properties` file.

You can read more [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/)

Comment: now getting exception as 
`Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'fix.connection.type' in value "${fix.connection.type}"`

Comment: if i place `fix.connection.type=initiator` at `application.properties` then is works fine but wont in case if i define it in `application-dev.properties`...why?

Comment: In which file you have specified `active profile` property?
It should be always specified in `application.properties` file as Springs always reads it at first.

Comment: yes, i have specified it in `application.properties`

Comment: If this property is located only in the `application-dev.properties` file, then you need to specify a default value in the @Value annotaiton @Value("${fix.connection.type:default}") or add `fix.connection.type` property with a default value to the `application.properties` file or add @Profile("dev") to the class itself, so it will be used only when this profile is active.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the annotation `@Profile("profile-name")` to determinate when to execute the method.

[Spring Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-profiles)